# Kubernetes pod still running even if js heap out of memory occur

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I'm running K8s 1.17 in AWS EC2 provisioned using kOps. I have a NodeJS pod which always reaches `JS heap out of memory`. I expect k8s will automatically kill my pod then restart it or liveness probe will take effect. Unfortunately, I can still fetch my health check API returning HTTP status code 200. Also, my nodejs pod `Status = Running`.

Is there a way that at least my pod should automatically get killed and restarted whenever js reaches its memory limit? Below is the logs from the pod:
[image]

Comment: If the service is still answering HTTP requests, has it actually failed?  Is there anything unusual about your container, or is it a basic image that runs `CMD ["node", "index.js"]`?  You seem to have included an image in place of the logs, is there any interesting content there beyond the "out of memory" error?

Answer (score 0):

An out of memory inside of the NodeJS runtime does not necessarily trigger a container restart. In other words, if the memory usage does not exceed what has been set as memory resource limit in the container's pod spec, then for kubernetes there is no reason to do an OOMKilled.
However, when a container terminates on its own, kubernetes will try to restart it depending on the restart policy. Of course there are other conditions when kubernetes terminates a container and restarts it, e.g. when the liveness probe fails.

So when your container is not restarted, it seems that kubernetes still believes that it is running normal. You say your health check still answers with status 200.

This looks like:

- health check is used for liveness probe and it is responding ok
- the main process of the container did not exit and is still running

So when you want your container to be restarted, make sure

- that the main process exits
- restart policy is set to always
- liveness probe behaves properly
- to set a memory resource limit to a lower value where you expect normal behavior of your application

Note about pods vs containers: a pod is an abstract construct - there is no process to kill or something. A pod consists of one or more containers that all have their own resource requests and limits and may get terminated when exceeding it. Kubernetes may terminate one container of a pod and restart it while other containers in the same pod still keep running.

Comment: You are right, k8s still believes my app is still running even though it is not working properly in reality. I want my pod to be automatically terminated and restarted if it JS heap out of memory occur

Comment: Then try to set a memory resource limit lower than what is your NodeJS heap usage.